# How to install a downloaded .deb file along with its dependencies in a system with an internet connection

Tags: apt, package-management, dpkg, internet

I thought when I executed `apt install pkg`, a deb file would be downloaded and put into `/var/cache/apt/archives`. But today after executing `apt install python2.7 python-pip`, I can't find any deb file in `var/cache/apt/archives`. I don't know why. Is it because I write `sudo apt install pkg` into a bash script and didn't execute the script with `sudo`?

For some reason, I need to be able to install some package from deb files, meaning that I should be able to execute `dpkg -i pkg.deb`, instead of `apt install pkg` to do the installation.

I've tried the command `apt download pkg` and it did download a deb file but it is a tiny file. When I execute `dpkg -i pkg.deb`, there are many errors about dependencies and I have to execute `apt install -f` to solve them.

My system has a working internet connection. How can I get a complete .deb package?

Comment: Possible duplicate of [How do I install a .deb file via the command line?](/q/40779/175814)